What is the origin of the "one" pronoun
There are many pages of questions on the "one" pronoun, so I apologise if this has been asked before. I would like to know the origin of the "one" pronoun. Ideally as much info as possible, but especially:

Where it comes from
If there is any meaning/explanation behind it
If it's connected to the number one
If it's connected to the "one" in someone
If it's got any connections with monotheism


see:
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30954/etymology-of-impersonal-pronoun-one
TL;DR
Origin is uncertain. Most likely a link to the word for 'man'. Little evidence of a link to 1 or someone. No indication that monotheism comes into it.
